# ファイル内に記載されている文字が読み込めません

Tags: c

knap10.txtに

```
10
39.0 13.0 68.0 15.0 10.0 20.0 31.0 15.0 41.0 16.0
42.0 12.0 45.0  5.0  2.0 61.0 89.0 32.0 47.0 18.0
```

と、数字を打ち込んだのですが、その数字が読み込めません。
ちなみに私は以下のようにプログラムをしました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

const int NMOJI=50;
const int MAX_ITEM=100;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j;
    int nitem;
    double capacity;
    double weight[MAX_ITEM],value[MAX_ITEM];
    char file_name[NMOJI];
    printf("Data Flie Name: ");
    scanf("%s",file_name);
    if((fp=fopen(file_name,"r"))==NULL){
        printf("%s:そのファイルを開けることはできません。\n",file_name);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Knapsack capacity: ");  scanf("%lf",&capacity);
    printf("データファイル名： %s\n",file_name);
    printf("ナップサック容量： %f\n",capacity); 
    printf("\n");
   
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&nitem);
    if(nitem>MAX_ITEM){
        printf("アイテム数を%3d以下にしてください.\n",MAX_ITEM);
        return -1;
    } 
    for(i=0;i<nitem;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&weight[i]);
    for(i=0;i<nitem;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&value[i]);
    fclose(fp);
  
    return 0;
}
```

ここで、   `fscanf(fp,"%d",&nitem);`　　にて、一番上段の10を

```
 for(i=0;i<nitem;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&weight[i]);
    for(i=0;i<nitem;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%lf",&value[i]);
```

で、上から二段目の重さと、一番下の価値を読み込めると思ったのですが、なぜか実行結果は

```
$ ./a.out
Data Flie Name: knap10.txt
Knapsack capacity: 121
データファイル名： knap10.txt
ナップサック容量： 121.000000
```

としかでてきません。自分は「fscanf」関数は、ファイル内の文字を読み込むものだと思っていたので、どこがおかしいのかがわかりませんでした。なぜ、ファイル内の数字が読み込めないのでしょう。

Comment: このコードだと、画面表示から読み込めたかどうか判断できないのでは?

Answer (score 0):

おそらく、ファイル読み込みは成功しているのではないでしょうか。読み込み成功しても何も表示をしていないので、「ナップサック容量」の行で終わるのは正常です。

正常に読み込めたかどうか判定するために、以下のようにコードを修正してはどうでしょうか。

```c
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &nitem) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "アイテム数を読めませんでした\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (nitem > MAX_ITEM) {
    fprintf(stderr, "アイテム数を%3d以下にしてください.\n", MAX_ITEM);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < nitem; i++) {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &weight[i]) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%d番目の重量の値を読めませんでした.\n", i + 1);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < nitem; i++) {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &value[i])) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%d番目の価値の値を読めませんでした.\n", i + 1);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  printf("%dアイテムの読み込みが完了しました.\n", nitem);
```